# How to style child component from parent component css?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html, slds, parent-to-child

I have two components that have a parent and child relationship. I am trying to apply css from the parent component's css file to the child component without having to write it in multiple places.

**Question**

1. How can I use the parent css (parent component) file to style the child component?

**Expected results:**

1. Any style set from the `parentTree.css` should cascade down to the child

**Actual results:**

1. No styling is cascaded down to the child

**What I tried that didn't work**

`childTree.html`

```
<template>
        <div class="childTree">
            <template for:each={branches.items} for:item="branch">
                <c-child-tree key={branch.id} branch={branch}></c-child-tree>
            </template>
        </div>
</template>
```

`parentTree.html`

```
<template>
    <div class="parentTree">
        <template for:each={branches} for:item="branch">
           <c-child-tree key={branch.id} branch={branch}></c-child-tree>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

`parent.css`

```
.parentTree, 
.parentTree c-child-tree {
  color: red;
}

c-child-tree .childTree {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> No styling is cascaded down to the child

This is because of the default behavior, the closed [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-dom.html).

In order to allow this behavior, you must make the child component a [Light DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-light-dom.html) component.

Change the child component's template tag to:

```
<template lwc:render-mode="light">
```

And in the ChildTree class, set a static variable, like this:

```
export default class ChildTree extends LightningElement {
  static renderMode = "light";
  // rest of class
}
```

This will allow you to apply styles and query child DOM elements.

Comment: when i used the light dom, i still did not get the css to cascade down to the child. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/415901/how-to-inherit-css-from-parent-within-the-child-using-light-dom. Do you have any thoughts as to why?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately CSS styles defined in a parent component aren't able to reach into a child component due to CSS encapsulation in the Shadow Dom. Parent components can only style child components as a single element, for example adding a border around the entire child component. This is detailed in the Docs here: [CSS Stylesheets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-components-css.html)

This means we have two approaches:

1. As per sfdxfox's answer, utilise [Light DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-light-dom.html)!
2. Update the Stylesheet in each component (parent and child)
3. Create a shared CSS module that you can import into your components. This involves creating a new LWC that only contains a CSS and configuration file before importing this into your other components. There's more detail on doing this here: [Share CSS Style Rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-components-css-share.html)

Comment: Don't forget about the Light DOM.

Comment: Good callout, I haven't used that before so thanks for calling that out!

Comment: @CallumMacErlich i tried to use light dom but didnt work. added a separate question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/415901/how-to-inherit-css-from-parent-within-the-child-using-light-dom